# String to event

Tags: c#

I'm trying to programmatically call a function with event.

How to convert string to a event in general? My problem is actually not knowing How to do this?

How to convert str to event?

```
str = "test1";

// UserControlsBackgroundEventArgs = EventArgs 
EventArgs arg = (EventArgs)str; --> ?
UserControlsBackgroundOutput(str); 



//function 
private string CLICKNAME = "test0";
private void UserControlsBackgroundOutput(EventArgs e)
{    
    if (CLICKNAME == e.output)
        return;

    if (e.output == "test1"){}
}
```

**Error solved:**
I had to do

```
UserControlsBackgroundEventArgs arg = new UserControlsBackgroundEventArgs(CLICKNAME);
```

instead of

```
UserControlsBackgroundEventArgs arg = new (UserControlsBackgroundEventArgs)(CLICKNAME);
```

Comment: We have no idea what `UserControlsBackgroundEventArgs` is, which makes it hard to help you... your question is very unclear at the moment. Please read http://tinyurl.com/so-list (You're not even trying to convert a string to an *event* - you're trying to convert it to an instance of your `UserControlsBackgroundEventArgs` class, which isn't an event...

Comment: As it stands now all I can say is that `UserControlsBackgroundEventArgs` should have property that will be holding value of `str`. Can you add more context to your question, please? What's real world usage?

Comment: what do you mean by `UserControlsBackgroundEventArgs = EventArgs`? is it the same class?

Comment: UserControlBackgroundEventArgs is a custom made event like EventArgs of a button click.

Comment: @Power-Mosfet: Please show us the (important parts of the) code of this class.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i've written a code that mimic you code, hopefully you will find it useful:

```
public class UserControlsBackgroundEventArgs
{
  public string output;

  public UserControlsBackgroundEventArgs(string up)
  {
     output = up;
  }
}

public delegate void UserControlsBackgroundOutputHandle(UserControlsBackgroundEventArgs e);

public class testEvent
{
  public event UserControlsBackgroundOutputHandle UserControlsBackgroundOutput;

  public void DoSomeThings()
  {
     // do some things

     if (UserControlsBackgroundOutput != null)
     {
        string str = "test1";

        UserControlsBackgroundEventArgs arg = new UserControlsBackgroundEventArgs(str);
        UserControlsBackgroundOutput(arg); // you've done that with str, whitch makes me
                                          // you don't know what the event param is
     }
  }
}

public class test
{
  private testEvent myTest;
  private const string CLICKNAME = "whatever"; // i don't know what you want here

  public test()
  {
     myTest = new testEvent();
     myTest.UserControlsBackgroundOutput += UserControlsBackgroundOutput;
  }

  void UserControlsBackgroundOutput(UserControlsBackgroundEventArgs e)
  {
     if (CLICKNAME == e.output)
        return;

     if (e.output == "test1")
     {
     }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your event class needs to have a constructor accepting a string. Then you will be able to create a new event instance using a string. You can't "convert" a string to an instance of the event class. If the event class comes from a library or sth and doesn't have a string constructor, you can subclass it, implement a string constructor and override the output property.

Answer (score 0):

Your `UserControlsBackgroundEventArgs` Implementation could provide implicit/explicit casts.

Take a look at [implicit keyword documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/z5z9kes2.aspx)

However, the answer from Wojciech Budniak is better.

Answer (score 0):

If you want this kind of conversion to be possible, you have to use an [`explicit operator`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/xhbhezf4%28v=vs.80%29.aspx):

```
public static explicit operator UserControlsBackgroundEventArgs(string s)
{
    var args = new UserControlsBackgroundEventArgs();
    args.output = s;
    return args;
}
```

This is only possible with a new class, not with `EventArgs`, because you can't change the code of that class.